# Tabulator header color

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tabulator

Tabulator does not accept header color change

Through the css below, I'm trying to change the header color of all my columns, but I'm not getting this adjustment

tried to do it this way but it's not going.
I use vue3 + vite + tabulator 5.4

```
<style scoped>
   .tabulator {
     font-size: 12px;
     width: 100%;
   }
   .tabulator .tabulator-header,
   .tabulator-col .headerBackgroundColor {
     background-color: #acacac;
   }
</style>
```

this is my tabulator

```
tabulator.value = new Tabulator('#tabulator', {
     data: dataRelatorio.value,
     layout: 'fitColumns',
     autoResize: true,
     pagination: 'local',
     paginationSize: 20,
     rowHeight: 25,
     paginationSizeSelector: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
     movableColumns: true,
     paginationCounter: 'rows',
     responsiveLayout: 'hide',
     placeholder: 'No record found',
     locale: 'pt-BR',
     langs: {
       'pt-BR': {
         pagination: {
           page_title: 'Show page',
           first: 'First',
           first_title: 'First page',
           last: 'Next',
           last_title: 'Next page',
           prev: 'Previous',
           prev_title: 'Previous page',
           next: 'Next',
           next_title: 'Next Page',
           all: 'All',
         },
       },
     },
     columns: columns,
     rowFormatter: function (row) {
       //console.log(row.getData());
       if (row.getData().in_delayed === 'delayed') {
         const children = row.getElement().childNodes;
         children.forEach((child) => {
           child.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFACD';
         });
       }
     },
   });
```

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```html
<style>
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col {
  background-color: #acacac;
}
</style>
```

**Notes:**

- I didn't use the `scoped` directive on `<style>` tag.
- you can have more than one `<style>` tag in a component, some `scoped` and some regular. The regular ones are *"normal"* CSS, they apply to the entire DOM.
- you can also apply the above styles inside a `scoped` style tag. The selector would most likely be `.tabulator :deep(.tabulator-header .tabulator-col)`, but I can't know for sure until you provide a *runnable* minimal example, so I could inspect it.

Comment: I understand, I thought I would have to pass it as a scope, but taking it out really worked, thanks.